# Passign attribute name as parameter automatically in Java-8

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to have a method to validate fields kind of

```
protected void validate(String field, String fieldName){
  if (field==null || field.isEmpty){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter " + fieldName + " cannot be empty");
  }
}
```

and use in my class for example

```
class Foo {
  private String x;
  private String y;

  ...

  public void validateAll(){
    validate(x, "x");
    validate(y, "y");
  }
}
```

It would be great to use in this way

```
  public void validateAll(){
    validate(x);
    validate(y);
  }
```

and let the compiler pass the name of the variable automatically to validate(field, fieldName) method

How can I achive this in Java-8 ?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Some context on where and why you want to do that will help helping you (as in, maybe you should not try to do that, but use one of the many validating frameworks out there).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Java by abandoning the idea of having java classes with fields, and instead having a `Map` which maps `Column` objects to values.  From a usage standpoint, it would look roughly like this:

```
public static final Column<String> X_COLUMN = new Column<>( "x", String.class );
public static final Column<String> Y_COLUMN = new Column<>( "y", String.class );
public static final Table FOO_TABLE = new Table( "Foo", X_COLUMN, Y_COLUMN, ... );
...
Row fooRow = new Row( FOO_TABLE );

fooRow.setFieldValue( X_COLUMN, "x" );
String x = fooRow.getFieldValue( X_COLUMN );

for( Column<?> column : fooRow.getTable().getColumns() )
    doSomethingWithField( fooRow, column );

private static <T> void doSomethingWithField( Row row, Column<T> column )
{
    T value = row.getFieldValue( column );
    ...do something with the field value...
}
```

Comment: it seems a quite complex approach :-(

Comment: Would you have preferred a "That is not possible." comment?  C-:=

Answer (score 0):

Since a value passed as argument to a method bears no information about the field it originated from, *if* it was read from a field at all, you can’t reconstruct this information. However, since your intent to verify *fields*, the desired operation is possible when processing the fields in the first place, rather than their contained values:

```
class Foo {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    //...

    public void validateAll() {
        for(Field f: Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && !f.getType().isPrimitive()) try {
                Object o=f.get(this);
                if(o==null || o.equals(""))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(f.getName()+" cannot be empty");
            } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) { throw new AssertionError(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The general problem of this approach is that by the time `validateAll()` reports a problem, the `Foo` instance already contains the illegal state. It’s preferable to reject invalid values right when they are attempted to set for a property. In that case, the parameter name of the method might not be available reflectively, however, when a method named `setX` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` (as would be indicated by the stack trace), there is no need for an additional meta information in the message…